# Filter data in a model with list of ids filtered from the related model

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

I've 3 models which are related weirdly though it is a one-to-many relationship (between 2 models). Now I've no option to change the model structure but to work with it however it is.

**Models**

```
class Note(models.Model):
    user_owner = models.ForeignKey('User',blank=True, null=True,related_name='note_owner')
    message = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    ... ... ...

class SalesLead(models.Model):
    user_owner = models.ForeignKey(User, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.ForeignKey(LeadStatus, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    ... ... ...

class LeadNoteRelation(models.Model):
    note = models.ForeignKey(Note, models.DO_NOTHING, primary_key=True, related_name = "lead_note")
    lead = models.ForeignKey('SalesLead', models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('note', 'lead'),)
```

I'm trying to write a function-based view which takes the `SalesLead id` and `User id` as inputs. The response should include all `Notes` related to this lead id and `user_owner` as the input User id

I tried:

```
LeadNoteRelation.objects.filter(lead__id = INPUT ID).select_related()
```

But this did not give me the desired result. Kindly help me with this one. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
Note.objects.filter(
    leadnoterelation__lead_id=lead_id,
    user_owner_id=user_owner_id
).distinct()
```

Where you replace *`lead_id`* and *`user_owner_id`* with the primary keys of the lead and user respectively. The [**`.distinct()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) can be used to avoid fetching the same `Note` multiple times per `lead_id` that matches.

Comment: By `lead_note__lead_id` are you using the related name from `LeadNoteRelation` model?  Because trying this is throwing a `FieldError`. Can you help me understand this better

Comment: `Note.objects.filter(leadnoterelation__lead_id = LEAD ID, user_owner_id = USER ID).distinct()` worked for me. Thanks a lot for idea

Comment: @vvk24: ah yes, sorry. Fixed.